# DotRas error enumerating devices - RasException (Error code 1070)

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, vpn, ras, pptp

Then trying to execute the following line:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<RasDevice> list = RasDevice.GetDevices();
```

I get a very non-helpful `RasException (Error code 1070)`.

This is also thrown when executing

```
RasDevice.GetDeviceByName(...);
```

I have ran the application as administrator.

Is there a reason why enumerating the available devices may fail?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: No I didn't figure this out. I was having the problem on Windows 8.1 x64 and the same code worked without error on XP. Please do post a solution if you find one.

Comment: Let me know if the answer I posted solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the WAN miniport, so I checked them into Device Manager and had a little yellow Icon on them saying

> "This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the
>   drivers required for this device. (Code 31)".

So after some hours of research I came across this website and it gave a solution that solved my problem. I'll post it here, maybe It can help you.

https://www.vpnhosting.cz/index.php/clanky/wan-miniport-repair-tool-solve-vpn-and-dial-up-error-code-720-and-similar-ppperrors.html

and these are the istraction you've to follow:

1. Run Wan miniport repair tool.
2. Restart Computer.
3. run Wan miniport installer.
4. Restart computer again and enjoy.

I hope this can help!